# Codeigniter: Change arguments of database dynamically

Tags: codeigniter

Can we change arguments like host-name, user-name, password and database dynamically or we must go to database.php to change it.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '****';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
```

Is there any possibility to change them dynamically?

Comment: Are you trying to change database connections within different portions of the same site or just change connections based on site environment?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work, in a model or Library.

```
$dynamic = array(
  'hostname' => 'localhost',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '*****',
  'database' => 'database'
);
$test['hostname'] = $dynamic['hostname'];
$test['username'] = $dynamic['username'];
$test['password'] = $dynamic['password'];
$test['database'] = $dynamic['database'];
$test['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$test['dbprefix'] = '';
$test['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$test['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$test['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$test['cachedir'] = '';
$test['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$test['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$test_db = $this->load->database($test, true);
```

Then you would access this database, like this;

```
$test_db->get('users');
```

Where are you planning on getting the `$dynamic` settings from?

Comment: i want to make an form for database setting, instead of going in database.php to configer

Comment: The code I posted will connect to a database, using the details in the `$dynamic` array. Where you get this data from, is up to you.